# How to rollback failed transaction in rails console with pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

When trying out new `active_record` queries in the rails console with `pry` loaded, if a query causes an exception, I often have to stop the console and start it again, otherwise all queries cause an exception.  I did have some code which appeared to fix this:

```
# .pryc
Pry.config.exception_handler = proc do |output, exception, _pry_|
  output.puts "#{exception.class}: #{exception.message}"
  output.puts exception.backtrace.first

  if exception.instance_of?(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) && exception.original_exception.is_a?(PG::Error)
    output.puts 'Rolling back transaction and starting a new one!'
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    connection.rollback_db_transaction
    connection.begin_db_transaction
  end
end
```

but it appears to have stopped working in rails 5. The problem appears to be that `exception.original_exception` now raises this error

```
<NoMethodError: undefined method `original_exception' for #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:0x00007fd2ceb4ba10>>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean "stopped working"? All queries are failing again in the console?

Comment: All active_record type queries fail.